# Videos of changing the orientation of an astronaut in space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, specific-reference, rotational-dynamics, space, conservation-laws

Kane, Headrick and Yatteau describe in their paper "[Experimental investigation of an astronaut maneuvering scheme](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021929072900607)" possible maneuvers to change the orientation in space without external torque. Is there any video (best available in the web) which shows real astronauts doing such motions?

Comment: This is a surprisingly rich and interesting subject.   See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_cat_problem

Comment: A quick search led me to [Skylab Gymnastics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmnmuTv4pGE). This is the advanced class, I couldn't find the beginner's version!